# Excel VBA to loop through tabs copy and paste in a separate file one below the other …

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out a way to code a macro that goes through tabs in a workbook with specific names and copy and paste the data of a certain range
into a new file one below the other...

i tried the following (see code below....)

This obviously is not working since its pasting the data in the same cell F2 for all data...
Can anyone suggest the best way to go down to the next cell after the pasted data for example if the the first data (source "10000") is
pasted in cells F2:R30 I want the next data for (source "20100") to be pasted right below in cells F31:R62 and so on...

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks

---

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportData()
Dim fPath As String
Dim fName As String
Dim thisFile As String
Dim thisTab As String
Dim fSheets As Variant
Dim fSheet As Variant
'
'
fPath = "C:\CliffTemp\ProjectionsFile_TY.xlsx"
fName = "Projections_TY.xlsx"
thisFile = "Projections_ReportingTEMP.xlsm"
thisTab = "Projections"
'

fSheets = Array("10000", "20100", "30101", "40200", "50300")

    'Update Projections_ReportingTEMP file

    'Open Projections_TY file: Projections_TY.xlsx
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled 'fixes the "Code error msg..
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fPath, UpdateLinks:=False
    Windows(fName).Activate

    For Each fSheet In fSheets
    Sheets(fSheet).Select


    Range("G3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(TRIM(CELL(""filename"")),6)"
    Range("G3:T120").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows(thisFile).Activate
    Sheets(thisTab).Select
    Range("F2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    'Activate Projections_TY.xlsx
    Windows(fName).Activate

    Next fSheet
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you want, but you can modify this a bit and tailor it for you own needs, this code I use consolidates the sheets in newly created one so instead of pasting the whole data, you can just copy paste the range you want:

```
Sub ConsolidateSheets()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim WS_consolidated As Worksheet
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Set WB = ActiveWorkbook

    Set WS_consolidated = WB.Worksheets.Add
    WS_consolidated.Name = "Consolidated"

    For Each WS In WB.Worksheets
        If WS.Name <> "Consolidated" Then
            WS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
            If WS_consolidated.UsedRange.Address = "$A$1" Then
                WS_consolidated.Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            Else
                With WS_consolidated
                    Set cell = .Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1)
                End With
                cell.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to try to avoid `Select` and `Activate`in your code.

Set the row to a variable which you can increment by 118 every time you loop (since `G3:T120` is 118 rows high)

```
myRow = 2 'This is the row variable
For Each fSheet In fSheets
    Sheets(fSheet).Range("G3").FormulaR1C1 = "=RIGHT(TRIM(CELL(""filename"")),6)"
    Windows(thisFile).Sheets(thisTab).Range("F" & myRow & ":S" & myRow + 117).Value = Sheets(fSheet).Range("G3:T120").Value
    myRow = myRow + 118

    'Activate Projections_TY.xlsx
Next fSheet
```